# Respond to an email where someone claims not to have received my answer to an invitation

Tags: email

I was invited to a professional event about two weeks ago, and I immediately replied that I am able to attend.

Today I received a reminder from the host, claiming that I have not yet responded.

How am I able to let the host know that I have already accepted the invitation, in a polite way?

Comment: `Thank you X, I would like to attend the event.` Here's the optional bit: `I'm sorry for the delay, I thought I had already replied but it seems the email didn't go through.` Your host was courteous enough to resend the invitation. You graciously accept. That's it.

Comment: Go to your "Sent" folder, and do a Reply To All with an additional message something like "Sorry, you didn't get my reply earlier."

Comment: @WorkerDrone it is customary to allow a person to **save** face, not rub his face in something.

Comment: Definitely OP should ask for a confirmation that they receive his follow-up reply, or maybe even call if there is a number.  If the initial response wound up in a spam tank, confirmations could be heading there, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply reply as you did the first time. Unless it's a systematic problem that might warrant investigation (technical problem, junk mail), then there's no benefit in pointing it out.  It's unlikely anyone will ever put two and two together once they meet you.

The vast majority of events are either (a) sign up now or lose your spot, or (b) few people RSVP unless prodded.